# How do I fix 'Multiple NSEntityDescriptions claim the NSManagedObject subclass'?

Tags: unit-testing, core-data, xctest, xctestcase

I know I'm not alone because I've looked at previous questions and answers about this problem but none of them have helped me solve my issue.

I'm getting these errors in the console when I run my unit tests:

```
Test Suite 'Selected tests' started at 2023-07-12 07:40:26.855
Test Suite 'My 1 Rep Max Tests.xctest' started at 2023-07-12 07:40:26.856
Test Suite 'DataControllerTests' started at 2023-07-12 07:40:26.856
Test Case '-[My_1_Rep_Max_Tests.DataControllerTests test_fetchLiftNames]' started.
container is about to be initialized and inMemory is true
Here's a datacontroller from setUpWithError <My_1_Rep_Max.DataController: 0x60000296c000>
Entity: Formula, Class: My_1_Rep_Max.Formula
Entity: Lift, Class: My_1_Rep_Max.Lift
Entity: LiftEvent, Class: My_1_Rep_Max.LiftEvent
Test Case '-[My_1_Rep_Max_Tests.DataControllerTests test_fetchLiftNames]' passed (18.144 seconds).
Test Case '-[My_1_Rep_Max_Tests.DataControllerTests test_newLiftEvent]' started.
container is about to be initialized and inMemory is true
Here's a datacontroller from setUpWithError <My_1_Rep_Max.DataController: 0x60000296c000>
2023-07-12 08:00:34.131784-0700 My 1 Rep Max[3038:55798] [error] **warning: Multiple NSEntityDescriptions claim the NSManagedObject subclass 'My_1_Rep_Max.LiftEvent' so +entity is unable to disambiguate.
CoreData: warning: Multiple NSEntityDescriptions claim the NSManagedObject subclass 'My_1_Rep_Max.LiftEvent' so +entity is unable to disambiguate.
2023-07-12 08:00:34.132390-0700 My 1 Rep Max[3038:55798] [error] warning:    'LiftEvent' (0x600003d3c160) from NSManagedObjectModel (0x600002960280) claims 'My_1_Rep_Max.LiftEvent'.
CoreData: warning:       'LiftEvent' (0x600003d3c160) from NSManagedObjectModel (0x600002960280) claims 'My_1_Rep_Max.LiftEvent'.
2023-07-12 08:00:34.132530-0700 My 1 Rep Max[3038:55798] [error] warning:    'LiftEvent' (0x600003d04160) from NSManagedObjectModel (0x600002974280) claims 'My_1_Rep_Max.LiftEvent'.
CoreData: warning:       'LiftEvent' (0x600003d04160) from NSManagedObjectModel (0x600002974280) claims 'My_1_Rep_Max.LiftEvent'.
2023-07-12 08:00:34.132656-0700 My 1 Rep Max[3038:55798] [error] error: +[My_1_Rep_Max.LiftEvent entity] Failed to find a unique match for an NSEntityDescription to a managed object subclass
CoreData: error: +[My_1_Rep_Max.LiftEvent entity] Failed to find a unique match for an NSEntityDescription to a managed object subclass**
Entity: Formula, Class: My_1_Rep_Max.Formula
Entity: Lift, Class: My_1_Rep_Max.Lift
Entity: LiftEvent, Class: My_1_Rep_Max.LiftEvent
Test Case '-[My_1_Rep_Max_Tests.DataControllerTests test_newLiftEvent]' passed (1189.141 seconds).
Test Suite 'DataControllerTests' passed at 2023-07-12 08:00:34.141.
     Executed 2 tests, with 0 failures (0 unexpected) in 1207.285 (1207.286) seconds
Test Suite 'My 1 Rep Max Tests.xctest' passed at 2023-07-12 08:00:34.142.
     Executed 2 tests, with 0 failures (0 unexpected) in 1207.285 (1207.286) seconds
Test Suite 'Selected tests' passed at 2023-07-12 08:00:34.142.
     Executed 2 tests, with 0 failures (0 unexpected) in 1207.285 (1207.287) seconds
```

I have a BaseTestCase class for my DataContollers tests:

```
class BaseTestCase: XCTestCase {
var dataController: DataController!
var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext!

override func setUpWithError() throws {
    dataController = DataController(inMemory: true)
    managedObjectContext = dataController.container.viewContext
   }
 }
```

and this DataControllerTests class which causes the errors to appear:

```
class DataControllerTests: BaseTestCase {

    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()

    }

    override func tearDown() {
        dataController = nil
        super.tearDown()
    }
    
    func test_newLiftEvent() {

        let liftEvent = LiftEvent(context: managedObjectContext)
        liftEvent.setValue(200.0, forKey: "weightLifted")
        liftEvent.setValue(3, forKey: "repetitions")

        XCTAssertNotNil(liftEvent)
    }

    func test_fetchLiftNames() {

        dataController.createSampleLiftData()

        let fetchedLifts = dataController.fetchLiftNames()

        XCTAssertEqual(fetchedLifts.count, 13, "Expected 13 standard lift names")
    }

}
```

You can see in the console messages that I've got 2 different managedObjectModels claiming 'LiftEvent' managed objects. It's only in the `test_newLiftEvent()` test that CoreData starts complaining.

I thought I was getting a good understanding of CoreData until I ran into this. How can I fix this?

Thanks!

**Update 1:**
I set some breakpoints and discovered something I didn't expect. The `func test_fetchLiftNames()`  test runs first and `func setUpWithError()` in BaseTestCase is called creating an instance of DataController. The test passes with no CoreDataErrors.

Next the `func test_newLiftEvent()` test runs and BaseTestCase is called again and a new DataController instance is created when `func setUpWithError()` is called. Then when the test actually runs, I get the CoreData errors.

This doesn't make sense to me. Any idea why it's called for each test?

Comment: Guess: The AppDelegate is creating a DataController. Could it be getting in the way of your tests? You can verify this by gutting your AppDelegate and running the test.

Comment: Do you get that log from running one test or is it multiple tests?

Comment: @JonReid - Thanks, Jon. I thought of that too but when I run the tests it starts the app and that data controller in the AppDelegate as to be created for the app to run.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson - it happens in both tests. I updated my question with the correct code and noted each place the warning is produced. I think it has to be the ```NSManagedObjectModel``` of the DataController created in AppDelegate fighting with the ```NSManagedObjectModel``` of the DataController created in BaseTestCase. My app won't launch without creating an instance of DataController so I don't see how that can be avoided.

Comment: @Jim Did you try gutting your AppDelegate to NOT do anything useful? This would be an experiment to determine if it's affecting the tests or not.

Comment: First of all, why does the tests start the app. Can't you run them without that overhead. And secondly, I would suggest implementing DataController as a shared type so you don't have any dependencies to the app delegate. For reference see the class that is generated by Xcode when you create a new Core Data project.

Comment: @JonReid - I tried your idea and although it didn't fix the problem, it helped me figure out that the DataController created in AppDelegate isn't contributing to the problem. Thanks

Comment: @JoakimDanielson - I wondered why the tests start the app myself. I'm not intentionally doing that so I assumed Xcode had its own reason for doing it. I'll look into using a shared instance of DataController. In the meantime, would you mind looking at the update I just added?

Comment: @Jim Okay thanks for checking. Yes, tests normally launch the app. Too bad it doesn't help for this, but FYI you can short-circuit it for tests https://qualitycoding.org/ios-app-delegate-testing/

Comment: It’s not surprising that the set up functions runs for each test since they are instance methods and also this is what you want almost all of the time when executing unit test so that you start with a clean sheet each time. There is a `class func setUp()` you can override to set something up for all your test but be careful with that, sharing state between test can quickly become a mess.